# Skype bot is not updating the response with HeroCard

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, azure-qna-maker

working on QnAMaker. The bot responses well with both Text and HeroCard responses on the Emulator and the WebChat. However, it is not sending the formatted HeroCard via my channel(Skype). I have rebuilt the application using build.cmd. Restarted the Azure services. Still no help.

```
// BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs:
 public RootDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService
        (new QnAMakerAttribute(
            RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey") == null ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"] : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"],
            Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId") == null ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"] : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
            "Not sure how to help with that. Try asking about the ALOTB, Pricing, Technology and scope to find more info or get in touch with sriram.chandrasekaran@epsilon.com", 0.5, 1,
            Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAEndpointHostName") == null ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"] : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"])))
    {
    }
    //override method
    protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
    {
        var answer = result.Answers.First().Answer;
        Activity reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply();
        string[] qnaAnswerData = answer.Split(';');
        int dataSize = qnaAnswerData.Length;

        if (dataSize > 1 && dataSize <= 6)
        {
            var attachment = GetSelectedCard(answer);
            reply.Attachments.Add(attachment as Attachment);
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }

    }

    private static Attachment GetSelectedCard(string answer)
    {
        int len = answer.Split(';').Length;
        switch (len)
        {
            case 4: return GetHeroCard(answer);
            default: return GetHeroCard(answer);
        }
    }

    private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string answer)
    {
        string[] qnaAnswerData = answer.Split(';');
        string title = qnaAnswerData[0];
        string description = qnaAnswerData[1];
        string url = qnaAnswerData[2];
        string imageURL = qnaAnswerData[3];
        HeroCard card = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = title,
            Subtitle = description,
        };
        card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>
        {
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Learn More", value: url)
        };
        card.Images = new List<CardImage>
        {
            new CardImage( url = imageURL)
        };

        return card.ToAttachment();
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Dragonthoughts for the response. I have added my code above. I am using the Preview mode of skype channel

Comment: Hi @RoshanSingh, What do url and imageURL look like? Does the URL you provide use https?